# angularjs:bug firing method that is bound to some other element

Tags: angularjs

I am not sure whether its a bug or something I am doing wrong. The problem is when I press enter on a text input a method is firing, the method firing is not bound to input text rather its bound to some other button. See jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LXAt7/175/

Press enter on textbox, you will see the alert, whey deleteIt method is firing?

html code:

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <form>
        <input type="text" />
        <button ng-click="deleteIt()">Delete</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

js code:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {  
    $scope.deleteIt = function() {
        alert('Firing');
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to fix this by setting `type="button"` explicitly:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="deleteIt()">Delete</button>
```

Explanation: as button doesn't have `type` set, it's treated like a button with a default `type` value - which is `submit`. Pressing `Enter` when editing field is treated as an attempt to submit it. It's easy to check what happens here by adding a submit handler:

```
<form ng-submit="submitIt()">
  <input name="abc" type="text" />
  <input name="def" type="text" />          
  <button ng-click="deleteIt()">Delete</button>
</form>

// in controller:
$scope.submitIt = function() {
    alert('Submit');        
};
$scope.deleteIt = function() {
    alert('Firing');
};
```

With those modifications, `Firing` will be alerted first, followed by `Submit` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LXAt7/176/)).

Comment: It does not matter whether form has one field or more, it fires the deleteIt method